# Opencv C - Cartesian to Polar image transformation

Tags: c, math, opencv, image-processing

Hi i want to transform a image like this (right to left image ):
[image]

I have searching about functions like cvCartToPolar but i dont know how to use it..

Can someone help me? :)

Comment: That function isn't what you need see the documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=carttopolar#void cartToPolar(InputArray x, InputArray y, OutputArray magnitude, OutputArray angle, bool angleInDegrees)

It transforms the coordinates form cartesian to polar or spherical in 3D.

Answer (score 3):

nowadays, there is [cv::warpPolar](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga49481ab24fdaa0ffa4d3e63d14c0d5e4) and if you can't achieve what you want (because for example your input image is only part of a disk, you might be interessed in [cv::remap](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gab75ef31ce5cdfb5c44b6da5f3b908ea4) (the former uses the later internally). 
In the later case, you have to build the mapping table yourself with some math.